# Selecting from multiple tables that use the same joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm not really sure how to explain what I need to do without an example, so I hope I can explain myself well enough!

Lets say I have the following tables in my MySQL database:

```
buyers
sellers
adverts
addresses
locations
object_addresses
```

The tables `buyers`, `sellers` and `adverts` are all "objects". They are associated with `addresses` by `object_addresses` which has `object_type`, `object_id` and `address_id`.

The `addresses` table has a `location_id` to associate it with a location.

What I ultimately want is to select all types of objects that are within a certain distance (by using a latitude and longitude I have on the `locations` table).

I don't have a problem with the distance calculation itself. However, I am having trouble selecting all "objects" along with their respective addresses/ locations (since they all make use of object_address).

I am able to do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM buyers as b
INNER JOIN object_addresses as oa on oa.ObjectId = b.Id
INNER JOIN addresses as a on oa.AddressId = a.Id
INNER JOIN locations as l on a.LocationId = l.Id
WHERE oa.ObjectType = 'buyer';
```

I'm having a hard time incorporating `sellers` and `adverts` into the statement above.

This is likely an simple answer, but I just can't see it tonight. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do `object_addresses` contains any related column for sellers and adverts ?

Comment: I've updated my question, but object_addresses simply has object_type (e.g. buyer, seller or advert), object_id and address_id.

Comment: What fields do you need from buyers and sellers? Do all 3 object types have common fields?

Comment: Ideally all/ any I choose. The three object types have some common fields (but not all are common, so lets say no).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM buyers as b
INNER JOIN object_addresses as oa on oa.ObjectId = b.Id
INNER JOIN addresses as a on oa.AddressId = a.Id
INNER JOIN locations as l on a.LocationId = l.Id
WHERE oa.ObjectType = 'buyer'
union
SELECT * FROM sellers as s
INNER JOIN object_addresses as oa on oa.ObjectId = s.Id
INNER JOIN addresses as a on oa.AddressId = a.Id
INNER JOIN locations as l on a.LocationId = l.Id
WHERE oa.ObjectType = 'seller'
```

etc?

if you don't like that - basically, you need to include the address bits multiple times - so that each one can be linked to each object type...

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want! The only issue with the union is that each select requires the same columns in each table which is, unfortunately, not the case for my schema!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using join on specific conditions `oa.ObjectType = 'seller',oa.ObjectType = 'advert',oa.ObjectType = 'buyer'` so only related result set will  join

```
SELECT * FROM buyers as b

INNER JOIN object_addresses as oa on (oa.ObjectId = b.Id AND oa.ObjectType = 'buyer')
INNER JOIN advert  as ad on (oa.ObjectId = ad.Id AND oa.ObjectType = 'advert')
INNER JOIN seller  as s on (oa.ObjectId = s.Id AND oa.ObjectType = 'seller')
INNER JOIN addresses as a on oa.AddressId = a.Id
INNER JOIN locations as l on a.LocationId = l.Id
```

Other solution would be join all your table and then check the object type

```
SELECT * FROM buyers as b

INNER JOIN object_addresses as oa on (oa.ObjectId = b.Id )
INNER JOIN advert  as ad on (oa.ObjectId = ad.Id )
INNER JOIN seller  as s on (oa.ObjectId = s.Id )
INNER JOIN addresses as a on oa.AddressId = a.Id
INNER JOIN locations as l on a.LocationId = l.Id
WHERE oa.ObjectType IN('buyer' , 'advert' , 'seller')
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think the problem is that this will produce a cross-product between `advert` and `seller`, not one row for each.

Comment: You need to rearrange the join order. You can't reference `oa.objectType` when joining advert since `object_addresses oa` hasn't yet been joined to. I think it would work if you did swapped `buyers as b` with `object_addresses oa`

Comment: @Barmar I have updated my answer i hope if  this  resolves the cross product

Comment: Now you'll join rows in `object_addresses` where `objectType` is `advert` with a row in `seller` whose ID matches `ObjectId`. Your original query got that part right.